# Can I credit an Apple user's account?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

When my app takes an in-app purchase, is it possible for the app to transfer some of the payment to another Apple user's account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't even give refunds (Apple can). You need to wait for your sales statements and do things manually. If you want to implement something like donations, no way.